# Convert an array of integers (or string) of binary 1s and 0s to their alpha equivalent in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary, ascii

I have an array of integer 1s and 0s (possibly need to get converted to `byte` type?). I have used [an online ASCII to binary generator][1] to get the equivalent binary of this 6 digit letter sequence:

`abcdef` should equal `011000010110001001100011011001000110010101100110` in binary.

My array is set up as `int[] curCheckArr = new int[48];` and my string is basically just using a `StringBuilder` to build the same ints as strings, and calling `toString()` - so I have access to the code as a string or an array.

I have tried a few different methods, all of which crash the browser, including:

```
StringBuilder curCheckAlphaSB = new StringBuilder(); // Some place to store the chars

Arrays.stream( // Create a Stream
    curCheckString.split("(?<=\\G.{8})") // Splits the input string into 8-char-sections (Since a char has 8 bits = 1 byte)
).forEach(s -> // Go through each 8-char-section...
curCheckAlphaSB.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s, 2)) // ...and turn it into an int and then to a char
);

String curAlpha = curCheckAlphaSB.toString();
```

and

```
String curAlpha = "";

for (int b = 0; b < curCheckString.length()/8; b++) {

    int a = Integer.parseInt(curAlpha.substring(8*b,(b+1)*8),2);
    curAlpha += (char)(a);
}
```

How can I most efficiently convert these 48 1s and 0s to a six digit alpha character sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each character is represented by precisely one `byte` you can iterate over the input with `Integer.parseInt()` (because `byte` value in the input is potentially unsigned):

```
String input = "011000010110001001100011011001000110010101100110";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 8) {
    int c = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i + 8), 2);
    sb.append((char) c);
}
System.out.println(sb); // abcdef
```

Comment: You may want to use `Integer.parseInt` to avoid sign issues.

Comment: Thanks both of you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex is probably the slowest part of these. Using a pre-compiled regex would help, but substring is faster.  Not creating any Strings except the result would be faster. e.g. use StringBuilder instead of `+=` for String.